# alert box disappear without clicking on ok button in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am making in which I want to display alert box and then redirect it to some other page in asp.net

My code is

```
 var s = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"].ToString());

        var q = (from p in db.students

            where p.userid == s
            select p.sid).SingleOrDefault();


        if (q == 0)
        {

            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "reg();", true);


        }
```

this is my reg() function

```
function reg() {
             var con = alert('Please Register Your Self Fisrt ..!! Thank you');

             window.location = "reg.aspx";

         }
```

My code is working fine but alert box gets disappear after some second without clicking on it because of that user is unable to read alert message
 I want to redirect it to reg.aspx but after clicking OK on alert box ..
please help

Comment: I'm not ASP developper but are you using custom `alert()` function or is that regular js one?

Comment: it's regular alert() js function

Comment: Maybe some behaviour is refreshing your page then as `window.alert()` method is modal. As a test, is still redirected if you remove `window.location = "reg.aspx";`?

Answer (score 0):

Firing a confirm box instead of alert will do what you are trying to achieve. You will have the option to redirect conditionally or unconditionally

```
function reg(){
    var con=confirm("You need to register first before proceeding. Redirect to Registration Page");

    if(con==true){
      window.location = "reg.aspx";
      }
   else{
        //if redirect unconditionally
        window.location = "reg.aspx";
    }
}
```